# Is it possible to force user log out if idle for a defined time?

Tags: drupal, user

We are using Drupal and CiviCRM 4.6.20.0.  We have some shared computers in our office and CiviCRM Users do not log out and just close their browser.  They do not get logged off CiviCRM.  If someone else interacts with CiviCRM from the same device expecting to be an unauthenticated person registering for an event or making a contribution, CiviCRM identifies them as the person who was logged on.  This is creating a problem where a users contact record is being updated with event registrations and contributions for others.

Can Drupal or Civi terminate the user's session if they are idle for a specified time and/or if they close the browser.

Answer (score 3):

This is really a Drupal question, since Drupal handles user login/logout and not CiviCRM. I suggest you ask at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/